# Isomorphism between two versions of $GF(2^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cyclotomic-fields

I have $GF(2^3)$ generated by $\Pi_1(\alpha)=x^3+x+1$ and $GF(2^3)$ generated by $\Pi_2(\alpha)=x^3+x^2+1$.

$\bullet$ $\Pi_1(\alpha)=x^3+x+1$ $000=0, 100=1,010=\alpha,001=\alpha^2,110=\alpha^3, 011=\alpha^4,111=\alpha^5,101=\alpha^6$

$\bullet$ $\Pi_2(\alpha)=x^3+x^2+1$ $000=0, 100=1,010=\lambda,001=\lambda^2,101=\lambda^3, 111=\lambda^4,110=\lambda^5,011=\lambda^6$

The exampla say that $\alpha$ and $\lambda^3$ both have minimal polynomial $\Pi_1$ and thus $\alpha \iff \lambda^3$ form an isomorphism between the two version.

How can I see in a practical way this fact? Someone can explain me this concept?

Comment: It may be easier to show that $\alpha\mapsto 1/\lambda$ gives an isomorphism. This follows from the fact that the two polynomials are reciprocals of each other:
$$x^3\Pi_1(\frac1x)=\Pi_2(x)$$ implying that $\Pi_1(1/\lambda)=0$. Gandalf61's solution is, of course, just fine.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate because that other question studies exactly the same pair of extension fields. It may have been difficult for you to realize that this is likely the case. So, *no harm* intended. Just maintaining basic site hygiene.

Comment: This is a very interesting clarification! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Pi_1(\lambda^3) = (\lambda^3)^3 + \lambda^3 + 1 = \lambda^9 + \lambda^3 + 1$

But you know that $\lambda^7=1$. So $\lambda^9=\lambda^2$ and

$\Pi_1(\lambda^3) = \lambda^3 + \lambda^2 + 1 = \Pi_2(\lambda) = 0$

The complete isomorphism is as follows:

$0 \leftrightarrow 0 \\ 1 \leftrightarrow 1 \\ \alpha \leftrightarrow \lambda^3 \\ \alpha^2 \leftrightarrow \lambda^6 \\ \alpha^3 \leftrightarrow \lambda^2 \\ \alpha^4 \leftrightarrow \lambda^5 \\ \alpha^5 \leftrightarrow \lambda \\ \alpha^6 \leftrightarrow \lambda^4$